# "Open onto" vs. "open into"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs, phrasing

When is one preferred over the other?

This is in the context of the door to a large room. My sense is that "into" is preferred for closed spaces and "onto" for open spaces. This situation is kind of on the cusp.

Comment: Your analysis is good, but a door does not open *onto* a room of any size. To avoid getting your post closed, check our tour to see that you need to show a bit of research.

Answer (score 3):

[These Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=open+onto+the+living+room%2Copen+into+the+living+room%2Copen+onto+the+garden%2Copen+into+the+garden&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), for

- open onto the living room
- open into the living room
- open onto the garden
- open into the garden

[image]

support the sensible explanation you put forward.

- *Open onto the garden* seems to be used more often than *open into the garden*  (I'm sure this would be more pronounced with 'patio', most easily pictured as a 'flat space'), whereas
- *open into the living room* seems to be used more often than *open onto the living room* (I'm surprised people use the latter).

Of course, there are 'the doors are open into the garden' and 'the doors open into the garden' tokens commingled in these results.